# Sequence of bounded $L^1$ functions converging to a non $L^1$ function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I found an exercise asking:

"Consider a sequence $\{f_n\} \in L^1(X, \mu)$ which is bounded with respect to the $L^1$ norm and converges point-wise to $f$. Prove that $f \in L^1(X, \mu)$"

But if I consider $(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$ and the sequence:

$f_n(x)= \begin{cases} 1 \quad x \in [-n,n] \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

I have $f_n \to 1 =:f$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Every $f_n \in L^1(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$ but $f \notin L^1(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: If the measure $\mu $ is finite then question was right. Therefore chosing a Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$ is not the right think to do. check first if you measure is not a probalbilty measure

Comment: I agree with you. However there is not such an hypothesis in the text I found...

Comment: The "bounded" refers to the $L^1$-norm. Your sequence isn't bounded in that sense.

Comment: Are $f_n$ supposed to be bounded as functions or as elements in $L^1(X,\mu)$? Your sequence is not a bounded sequence....

Comment: Ok where did to this question from I am curious. Because this true only if $\mu $ is finite

Comment: @GuyFsone I think the question is true in general. Note that a sequence is called bounded in a normed space if it is bounded with respect to the norm, I think the OP is missreading the question.... Read again the question, it says that the sequence is bounded, not that the functions are bounded.

Comment: Please edit so that "bounded" is clear. It's not clear as it is.

Comment: Yes, I misread the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As remarked by N.S., the sequence is supposed to be bounded in $L^1(X,\mu)$, i.e., there exists a constant $C\geq 0$ such that
$$
\|f_n\|_1 := \int_X |f_n|\, d\mu \leq C,
\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Under this assumption, the claim is an easy consequence of Fatou's lemma, since
$$
\int_X |f|\, d\mu \leq \liminf_n \int_X |f_n|\, d\mu \leq C.
$$